# Merge two dataframes on datetime index and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes created like this:

```
date1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=3, freq='8H')
date2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=2, freq='12H')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': ['1', '1', '2']}, index = date1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': ['1', '2'],
                    'cat2': ['111', '222']}, index = date2)
df1.index = df1.index.map(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime().date())
df2.index = df2.index.map(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime().date())
```

They look like this:

```
print(df1)
print(df2)

           cat1
2011-01-01    1
2011-01-01    1
2011-01-01    2
           cat1 cat2
2011-01-01    1  111
2011-01-01    2  222
```

I would like to merge them on datetime index and the cat1 column. I would like to get this:

```
           cat1 cat2
2011-01-01    1  111
2011-01-01    1  111
2011-01-01    2  222
```

I attempt to get this by using:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', right_index=True, left_index=True, on='cat1')
```

But, instead I'm getting this:

```
           cat1 cat2
2011-01-01    1  111
2011-01-01    1  222
2011-01-01    1  111
2011-01-01    1  222
2011-01-01    2  111
2011-01-01    2  222
```

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something right in front of me, but I can't figure it out.

I actually over simplified the above scenario, so that the solution could not fix my actual problem. In my actual problem I have more dates.

The following more accurately represents my actual problem:

```
date1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-14', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-15'])
date2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-14', '2017-05-15', '2017-05-14', '2017-05-15'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': ['200', '200', '200', '100']}, index = date1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': ['200', '200', '100', '100'],
                    'cat2': ['111', '222', '333', '444']}, index = date2)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True, on='cat1')

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)

           cat1
2017-05-14  200
2017-05-14  200
2017-05-14  200
2017-05-15  100
           cat1 cat2
2017-05-14  200  111
2017-05-15  200  222
2017-05-14  100  333
2017-05-15  100  444
           cat1 cat2
2017-05-14  200  111
2017-05-14  200  222
2017-05-14  200  111
2017-05-14  200  222
2017-05-14  200  111
2017-05-14  200  222
2017-05-15  100  333
2017-05-15  100  444
```

But, for df3 I expect to get this:

```
           cat1 cat2
2017-05-14  200  111
2017-05-14  200  111
2017-05-14  200  111
2017-05-15  100  444
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there!

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', right_index=True, left_index=False, on='cat1')
```

Note the `left_index` kwarg :)

More in general, you may need to reset/set the index, so you can join based on indexes or on columns, without mixing the two. This should be working for the general case (now you are simply performing a join on two different columns, dropping both indexes):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['index','cat1']).set_index('index')
```

This is the same, ma more similar to previous solution

```
df3 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['index','cat1']).set_index('index')
```

Comment: This definitely works for the problem that I posted. Thank you! Unfortunately, what I posted was over simplified. I've edited the post slightly to show what I mean. Not sure if I should've made another question, but it's very similar. I feel like I've tried everything to make it work!

Comment: You should probably incude 'cat1' in the index (multi-index dataframe). You can user df1.reset_index().set_index(['index','cat1']) and so on. This should be working :)

edit: no, it's probably not going to work. I'll try something else

Comment: Much appreciation! So, essentially what I gather from this is that if I want to merge on column AND index, I should just make the indices into columns.

Comment: Or vice-versa: you can even set the column in index, then join on indexes:

`df1.set_index('cat1', append=True)` on both, then join as before and fix indexed again :)

Comment: I had tried that at one point. The problem was that I wanted to get back to a singular datetime index. I couldn't because of the non-unique dates.